# Размер переменных в функциях

Tags: c++, функции, память, выделение-памяти

Почему под параметр-переменную функции выделяется 4 байта оперативной памяти, если тип short (2 байта)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По просьбе dgzargo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: два параметра типа short. попробуй изменить тип одного из них

Comment: @dgzargo При чём тут это? Я ввёл два параметра, в оперативной они оба отображены: 02 00 00 00 - первый, второй такой же. Ввёл два затем, чтобы увидеть границу по памяти между первым и вторым

Comment: Выравнивание ? на границу размера указателя ? на 32x - 4 байта, на 64х - 8 байт.

Comment: @vegorov: Я думаю, что даже на x64 выравнивание все равно будет на `int`, т.е. на 4 байта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, в таком коде скорее всего под параметры вообще не будет выделена никакая память - параметры будут размещены в регистрах процессора.

Во-вторых, даже если ваша реализация решит разместить параметры в памяти, скорее всего она выровняет их либо на границу нативного слова вашей платформы, либо (еще вероятнее) на границу типа `int`.

Особенностью варианта с выравниванием на границу типа `int` является совместимость со "старинными" соглашениями, принятыми для вызова необъявленных функций в языке С: аргументы типа `short` порождают параметры типа `int`. Скорее всего это и является одним из доминирующих факторов в данном случае. Совместимость с соглашениями о передаче параметров языка С практически ничего не стоит, а заниматься какой-то ненужной "упаковкой параметров" только для С++ никакого смысла нет.

По этой же самой причине даже аргументы типа `char` будут передаваться как полноразмерные `int`, а аргументы типа `float` - как `double`.

P.S. Вас и не должно интересовать, сколько памяти было выделено под передачу ваших параметров. Это не имеет никакого значения. Внутри функции ваши параметры будут вести себя, как значения типа `short`, и их начальные значения будут переданы правильно.

Comment: Когда я пытаюсь реализовать функцию с переменным числом параметров, используя указатель, указатель (пусть типа short) получает адрес первого аргумента, а дальше смещается на 2 адреса в памяти, а аргумент занимает 4. Вот тут возникает проблема. Конечно, можно всё передавать как тип int или больший, но всё же

Comment: @Алексей: Так а зачем вы так делаете? Доступ к переменным параметрам делается через `va_arg`, а не через "смещение указателя".

Comment: Ещё не дошёл до этого, учу язык в свободное от учёбы время

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем случае параметры передаются через стек. А так как программа тридцати-двух битная то и квант стека соответственный. О передаче параметров в Visual Studio написано
[здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2017) и [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/overview-of-x64-calling-conventions?view=vs-2017).

> On x86 plaftorms, all arguments are widened to 32 bits when they are
>   passed.

Что такое фрейм стека и что и как там размещается написано [здесь](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195385/understanding-stack-frame-of-function-call-in-c-c) и [здесь](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs1917/12s2/lect/17_Memory4.pdf).